# logic:equal slow the performance for showing 10000 records

Tags: struts

I am having 10000 records

in jsp page 32 columns

29 colums i am using  and  it is slowing the process any other way

Whether  slows down because it is checking for every row.

user dont want pagination he needs to show all 10000 not 1000 records

I have a datalist which iterate , within the iterate loop i gave the logic:equal condition

..................................

for changing the bgcolor only i am using the logic:notequal

Any Idea

Answer (score 0):

Does he can read or print them all. What's a wasting of server/client resource and bandwidth! 

But in helpless case, you can you javascript to change color to redistribute server processing.
 Or use good load strategy, for example: not all at once but delay loading (use ajax I assume), load part in view first,..